# How to get the system time with date in milliseconds in c/c++ on vxworks

Tags: c++, vxworks

I have tried below to get the system time with date in miliseconds. 
It works fine on Linux platform but could not work on VXworks. I need similar solution for vxworks.

```
#include <sys/time.h> /* It seems this is not available on vxworks */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   struct timeval tp;
   gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);
   unsigned long int ms = tp.tv_sec * 1000 + tp.tv_usec / 1000;
   cout<<ms
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What didn't work? How did it not work?

Comment: Is `tv_usec` *microseconds* or milliseconds? I would expect the name to be `tv_msec` for milliseconds.

Comment: It gives the compilation error for #include <sys/time.h> on vxworks.

Comment: What kind of **data** do you want? `textual` or `time since epoch`

Comment: textual will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at the functions of [clockLib](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/clockLib.html).

The following code should do the trick:

```
#include <vxworks.h>
#include <timers.h>


struct timespec t;

if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t) == OK)
{
   /* t.tv_usec and t.tv_sec are valid */
}
```